How to get a picture of headphones on an Android device?
Is there any method or Android API that can obtain pictures of the left and right earphones and charging boxes that support Google Fast Pair headphones?
headphone picture sample
I thought about using some APIs to directly obtain the pictures of the left and right ears and the charging case of the Android device when it is connected to the headset device, but I can't find the relevant API, and I haven't found anyone on the Internet who has implemented it. Past cases

I have no experience with this whatsoever, but the answer is almost certainly "no". Using the Bluetooth API you should be able to get more details about the paired BT device, and from that you can select your own custom icon that you embed in your application.

I dug into the source code for the settings app, and how it is getting the images is by requesting metadata from the bluetooth device using BluetoothDevice.getStringMetaData.
According to the AOSP source, this requires the android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission, which is only given to system apps.
Unless this is changed, I don't believe it is possible to get the images. There's a very slight possibility that this could be done using a C/C++ library that interfaces with the bluetooth drivers directly rather than going through the java API, but I doubt that it would be possible to use that without rooting or some other sort of elevated privilege for your app anyways.
The best you can do is to get the device name and hardcode or host images for headphones you think might be used, using AudioDeviceInfo.getProductName or BluetoothDevice.getName
